# On Mouse over / on Getting focus, The Button Disappers in windows 8 metro app, How to disable that effect?

Tags: xaml, button, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, visualstates

In Many places in my application i am using buttons in the UI but my doubt is :-

1)when a button gets focus or when it is getting mouse over also , the button background disappears (i.e, it becomes invisible at that time),

After again  coming away from button (button losing focus) it shows up the button as usual

so , On mouse over / Getting focus the button behaves in this way.

What should i do if i dont want this effect. Please let me know .

2)i might be wrong, but my guess is that there should be some visual state property behind this , which i need to disable , but i dont know where where to disable ?? , please let me know it .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to retemplate the control so that you can override the visual states. You can do this easily inside Blend by right clicking in it and choosing to edit a copy of the style.